# Google current place accuracy in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm using google place API to get proper information of current place.
[I used this code in the App](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/current-place) and get success to fetch list of all nearby locations, but how can I recognize my exact current location from the list?

I read doc and find that we get current location from the list based on **likelihoods (value between 0 to 1)**.

> A higher value of likelihoods means a greater probability that the place is the best match.

But my current location is coming into this list but likelihoods value is not higher.

So I have two questions:

1) How can I recognize my exact current location? Any other setting is there or any alert-net way is there? *(Without use of place picker)*

2) If I leave current place then I want to perform some action so How can I get that I left this place recently? like checked-In/Out?

Comment: What value of likelihoods did you receive?

Comment: @KENdi - I received list of values that are in between 0 to 1 but value that is maximum is not my current place. So how can I get accurate values of likelihoods?

Answer (score 4):

Google's API requires that you initialize a CLLocationManager. Since you already have a location manager, you can set your class to be a CLLocationManagerDelegate. This provides you with native iOS methods that mean you can get both an exact location and a notification that the location has changed

To get an exact location:

```
[self.locationManager requestLocation]; //Get the current location once (iOS 9 and above)
```

To monitor location:

```
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation] // Ask for the current location until you call stopUpdatingLocation
// or
[self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges] // Tells you when your location has greatly changed
```

You then need to conform to the protocol, which has 2 methods at minimum:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
 didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations
// Do anything that you need to do once you have a location update

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
// Your location update failed, handle it
```

Comment: This will not help me because, CLLocationManager will not give me accurate information of my current location..like place name, fully address, rating etc.

Comment: You can pass the location returned by iOS to Google to get information about the location (known as reverse geocoding). The iOS location will give you a latitude and longitude, and you can give that to `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=xx.xxxxxx,-yy.yyyyyy&key=YOUR_API_KEY`. Here's a link to read more about it: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start
. Otherwise, the greatest likelihood is your best bet

Comment: This will not give me accurate location information like google place give me accurate information by list problem is only  likelihoods is wrong so I can't get proper information of the location.

Comment: What do you mean by "accurate location information"? I'm not following what you need because this will give you the device's exact latitude and longitude coordinates, which again you can pass to the Google API for business information such as name, address, etc

Comment: The coordinates you are getting are not 100% exact - there is a margin for error. Now, the APIs that have been described and the solution suggested so far do not account for that. To account for that you need to know your GPSs precision, and then calculate a range of positions based on it. In the end, if the precision is not good enough, you really can't know exactly where you are. My suggestion is to take several measurements, and then calculate an average position based on them.